# Adding Pivot Table Slicers in one box

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Currently I am using a pivot table to display information to users, they can edit the slicers to filter the table with what they want to see. As requirements grow, i find myself adding more and more slicers which take up too much space on the excel sheet.

Is there a way to put the slicers on one single form so that it looks intuitive and is easily navigated?

Best,
Grant